# Will recursion in uiview animation's completion block cause stack overflow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'd like to make an endless animation (e.g. making a view to move between two positions endlessly)

I wonder if this is a recursion and whether it would cause stack to overflow?
pesudo code:

```
-(void)doAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
            delay:0.0
            options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
            animations:^{
                if(view is at Position A){ 
                    set frame to Postion B;
                }else{
                    set frame to Positon A;
                }
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                [self doAnimation];
            }
     ];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to perform a repeating animation. Look at the animation options `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` instead ([documentation, see Constants at the end](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)) Your animation could be rewritten as follows:

```
-(void)doAnimation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
            delay:0.0
            options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)
            animations:^{
                set frame to Position B;
                }
            }
            completion:nil
            }
     ];
}
```

Assuming your view starts at position A.

Answer (score 4):

When your completion is called, the call stack has already been unwinded to the main run loop so, no, you won't get any stack overflow, just some infinite animation.

Comment: Good to know how run loop reacts with the completion block, though I'll take jrturton's answer for my particular case. Thanks!